# The app crashes when I click on the "Done" button on numeric keyboard

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
    final EditText edC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etC);
    final String creditsS = edC.getText().toString().trim();
    final TextView tvD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay); 

    tvD.setText("Enter amount of credits");

    edC.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            int credits = Integer.parseInt(creditsS);
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                tvD.setText("Your amount of credits" + credits);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and when I click the "Done" button, the app crashes. I don't understand where is the problem. Please help? Thanks!!!

Comment: And what does the logcat say?

Comment: Post a logcat please.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
final EditText edC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etC);
final TextView tvD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay); 

tvD.setText("Enter amount of credits");

edC.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        String creditsS = edC.getText().toString().trim();
        int credits = Integer.parseInt(creditsS);
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            tvD.setText("Your amount of credits" + credits);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

It's crashing because you're getting the value from edC before there is any value, so it's trying to parse an empty string and it crashes with NumberFormatException.

Comment: you still should better treat what the user is typing, you can still get `NumberFormatException`. And don't forget to mark the answer as correct.